# Min-max normalization when using tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, normalization, tensorflow-datasets, tf.data.dataset

I have a tf.Dataset and I want to perform a minmax normalization, in order to have image values in the range [0,1].

I am interested in knowing how to perform normalization on each image, as well as for the whole batch.

> @tf.function def load_images(imagePath):
>
> label = tf.io.read_file(imagePath)
> label = tf.image.decode_jpeg(label,
> channels=3)
> label = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(label,
> dtype=tf.float32)
>
> image=label+tf.random.normal(shape=tf.shape(label),mean=0,stddev=0.1**0.5)
>
> return image, label

> filenames = glob.glob("/content/mydrive/images/" + "*.jpg")

> trainDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
> trainDS = (trainDS
> .shuffle(len(filenames))
> .map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
> .batch(16)
> .prefetch(AUTOTUNE) )

Could anyone suggest what is the best way to do that?

P.S. I would expect that a tf.image.per_image_normalization function existed (similar as [tf.image.per_image_standardization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization)) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)` to perform a minmax normalization:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  batch_size=batch_size)

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))

for x, y in normalized_ds.take(1):
  # the pixel values are now in [0,1]
  print(tf.reduce_min(x), tf.reduce_max(x))
```

```
tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

If you want to normalize each image separately just change the batch size to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I was asking for normalization and not rescaling, because my image values (after applying Gaussian noise), are not in the range [0,1]. For example I have values such as: min -1.3447381 and max 2.3947003.
Could you suggest a way to achieve that?

Comment: How can they be in the [0, 1] range after adding noise? You obviously have to apply normalization afterwards.

Comment: @aDav what exactly is your question? Because I clearly showed how to squeeze your images between 0  and 1.

Comment: I believe the way you showed me is correct, but I don't know how to use it correctly. I am adding some noise when I am parsing the images inside the map function using tf.random.normal. Thus the images in the trainds are not in the [0,1] range when I load them. Can I somehow normalize them inside the map function as well?

Comment: Yes you can .. just call the normalization_layer after adding noise to your images inside the map function .. just like in my answer..

Comment: if I add the normalization layer as you showed (so, outside the map function), I assume that the scaling factor in tf.keras.layers.Rescaling should not be constant, but should be chosen according to the min-max of each image (or batch), instead of 1./255, right? But I don't know how to do that.
I am sorry, I will update the question to make it more clear.